# Text disappear after reloading a scene

Tags: android, ios, iphone, lua, coronasdk

in my app I have a timer that is meant to be paused when the player lost the game.

It works, but when I click on the replay button it disappear (I think it goes on the first layer of the localGroup)

Here's the code I used:

```
local myText = display.newText("", _W-30, 308, "PUSAB", 8)
myText.alpha = 1
myText:toFront()
localGroup:insert(myText)
myText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)




local score = 0
local secDisplay = ""
local distance = 100


local function updateScore()
    score = score + 1
    myText.text = secDisplay..score
end



myTimer = timer.performWithDelay(distance, updateScore, 0)


local function move(event)

if(rect.x < 12) then
    rect.x = 1000
    scrollSpeed = 0
    waveSpeed = 0
    youFlewFor.alpha = 0
    myText.alpha = 1
    backToMenu.alpha = 1
    planePlus = 0
    gameOver.alpha = 1
    tapToReplay.alpha = 0
    pause.alpha = 0
    check = 0
    timer.pause(myTimer)

    end


end


Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", move )
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible fixes:

1- Make sure that the runtime event listener is called after at least one updateScore, otherwise you will only see the initial score text ("") which is the same as saying invisible :)

2- Try adding myText:toFront() in the move / update function too to make sure it's in front of the local group.

Cheers